# Find and remove items from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the object below that is used by datatables, I want to know how to remove items by name.

Example

Lets say I want to remove sEcho, mDataProp_1 and sSearch from the object below, would the best way to loop through all items and check the name or is there a easier way.

```
[{"name":"sEcho","value":1},{"name":"iColumns","value":9},
{"name":"sColumns","value":""},{"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0},
{"name":"iDisplayLength","value":10},{"name":"mDataProp_0","value":0},
{"name":"mDataProp_1","value":1},{"name":"mDataProp_2","value":2},
{"name":"mDataProp_3","value":3},{"name":"mDataProp_4","value":4},
{"name":"mDataProp_5","value":5},{"name":"mDataProp_6","value":6},
{"name":"mDataProp_7","value":7},{"name":"mDataProp_8","value":8},
{"name":"sSearch","value":""},{"name":"bRegex","value":false},
{"name":"sSearch_0","value":""},{"name":"bRegex_0","value":false},
{"name":"bSearchable_0","value":false},{"name":"sSearch_1","value":""},
{"name":"bRegex_1","value":false},{"name":"bSearchable_1","value":false},
{"name":"sSearch_2","value":""},{"name":"bRegex_2","value":false}]
```

Examples would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little jsfiddle that do just that http://jsfiddle.net/wHkTS/

The idea is to iterate over the area and compare the name you want to remove with the currently iterate object name and basically build a new array to assign back that doesn't contain the object you want to remove.

```
var data = [
        {"name":"sEcho","value":1},{"name":"iColumns","value":9},
        {"name":"sColumns","value":""},{"name":"iDisplayStart","value":0},
        {"name":"iDisplayLength","value":10},{"name":"mDataProp_0","value":0},
        {"name":"mDataProp_1","value":1},{"name":"mDataProp_2","value":2},
        {"name":"mDataProp_3","value":3},{"name":"mDataProp_4","value":4},
        {"name":"mDataProp_5","value":5},{"name":"mDataProp_6","value":6},
        {"name":"mDataProp_7","value":7},{"name":"mDataProp_8","value":8},
        {"name":"sSearch","value":""},{"name":"bRegex","value":false},
        {"name":"sSearch_0","value":""},{"name":"bRegex_0","value":false},
        {"name":"bSearchable_0","value":false},{"name":"sSearch_1","value":""},
        {"name":"bRegex_1","value":false},{"name":"bSearchable_1","value":false},
        {"name":"sSearch_2","value":""},{"name":"bRegex_2","value":false}
    ];

function remove(name) {

    var arr = [], len, i;

    // we reset len as data.length will change after erach remove
    for(i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i].name != name) arr.push(data[i]);
    };

    data = arr;
};

console.log(data);
remove('sEcho');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The modern ES5 way is [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var original = [{"name":"sEcho","value":1}, ... ];

var filtered = original.filter(function(val, index, array) {
    var n = val.name;
    return n !== 'sEcho' && n !== 'mDataProp_1' && n !== 'sSearch';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to create a function that can search and then remove them, something like

```
function deleteByName(needle, haystack) {
 for(i in haystack) {
  if ( haystack[i].name == needle) { 
   haystack.splice(i,1);
 }
}
```